# 2010 Macbook pro makes intermitten beeping sound

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

It seems like every time I press a button or scroll on the touchpad I can hear little beeping noises coming from the hard drive area.

How can I know what this noise is and whether it's a problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Do you have any further details?  Is this a sudden change or persistent since using the machine?  Since upgrade of OS?  What is your OS X version?  Cheers

Comment: Just started happening today. And wasn't after updating.

Comment: Try rebooting?  Still happens?  Also, if you have a bluetooth keyboard or mouse packed in a backpack without turning it off, if something presses on it you will get some strange behavior.  False inputs as the buttons get pushed in the bag.

Comment: Ok will reboot now and report back.

Comment: Now it seems to have went away. But I suspect it might come back. When it started up the apple logo appeared as usual but made a high-pitched noise, not terribly but loud enough to be noticed.

Comment: Ok, it's back. Not when I pressed on the keyboard. But only when I click on the touchpad.

Comment: Ok _SOLVED_ the issue. Haha feel like a fool now. Someone loaned me their MacBook air charger instead of the MacBook pro charger. Apparently this cases these type noises. Ah a sigh of relief!

Comment: Glad you figured out the problem, but NEVER use a power adapter with a lower wattage than your computer is designed to be used with! A majority of the time, nothing bad happens, but in some cases very bad things can happen.

Comment: Oh I knew that. But the person I rented it from passed me the wrong charger and I didn't notice the size difference.

Answer (score 1):

Put a stethoscope next to where the hard drive is inside the case. It's highly likely you're hearing the servos and motors from the drive responding at the same time as you  interact with the system.

Comment: I was loaned the wrong charger. It was an apple air charger instead of a MBP charger. Apparently, this causes intermittent beeping sounds anything the user interacts with the interface.

Comment: Woah. Under voltage would make that noise too and possibly cause odd failures and increased motor noise at lower pitches. Can you self-answer with that critical piece of information?

Comment: Was it's working fine now. Nothing seems to have been damaged. So not harm done I suppose.